# Proof of different forms of derivative

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, proof-writing, solution-verification

State which of the following statements are true and which are false. Give a reason for your decision in each case.

1. $$f'(a)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(a+2t)-f(a)}{2t}$$
2. $$f'(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a)-f(a-h)}{h}$$
3. $$f'(a)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(a+2t)-f(a+t)}{t}$$

For the second one, I simply let a'=a+h. I thought if ${h\to0}$, then a'=a. Then I can replace a by a', and the second one is proved. But I'm not sure whether I can replace a by a'. And if I can do so, it seems like the first and the third one are also true.  I don't think the third one is true, but I can't find a counterexample for it. And I'm not sure about the first one's proof either.

Comment: Your substitution seems a bit weird to me. You will get that $h=a'-a$ which is a constant unless you intend to change the limit to $\lim_{a' \to a}$, in which case substituting $a$ for $a'$ would not be correct. Also, your expression (2) would become $$\lim_{a'\to a}\frac{f(a)-f(2a-a')}{a'-a}$$  A suggestion would be to consider $t=-h$ instead, what then becomes 2?

Comment: @André Armatowski I see where I got it wrong, but why can I take t = -h and let -h-->0?

Comment: Because $\lim_{h\to 0}$ means that (1) $h\to 0$ from the positive side and (2) $h\to 0$ from the negative side. If $t=-h$ then the roles of (1) and (2) are switched, but, we have still considered them both, so we can write $\lim_{t \to 0}$

Comment: @André Armatowski oh I forgot the definition for limits. Thx! By the way, if I use the same logic for the first one, taking t=2t, is it correct to imply 2t-->0  from t-->0?

Comment: Yes precisely! Although to avoid risk of confusion I would choose another variable.